# Is GWT Servlet model for RPC a single threaded model, or how to be Highly Available with GWT?

Tags: gwt, servlets

I need to implement a high availability service contained in a Tomcat instance. I'm using plain GWT with RPC mechanism to call the server from my client app. What I created is a method **com.ha.keepAlive()** in each remote service. The RPC methods do nothing other than respond '0' if all is ok. For now, if something is wrong I'm expecting an exception.

I was reading on [Java Servlet Specification 3.0](http://download.oracle.com/auth/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?e=1315335404&h=d6c0a42f8a64ea75cc90d63ef42b665d) and I'm concerned. The servlet can return UnavailableException or ServletException, but GWT has wrapped the HttpServlet so that exceptions are swallowed. I can still get exceptions from GWT and for any kind I'll suppose 'the service is down' as this should not happen.

Also, if a servlet somehow crashed, the servlet container could restart a servlet or it could have many instances of the servlet. By my readings (section 2.2) I found that usually there is only one instance:

> For a servlet not hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet 
>   container must use only one instance per servlet declaration. However, for a servlet 
>   implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, the servlet container may 
>   instantiate multiple instances to handle a heavy request load and serialize requests 
>   to a particular instance.

So, have I done right by creating a GWT-RPC method in each service (servlet) to suppose if I get an exception (or at some point something other than '0') I need to restart my Web Application container? I'm specially concerned by the multi-instance nature of a servlet which could hide real service availability.

Sorry I had to be so verbose. Thanks a lot to anyone having a piece of advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't restart the container. An exception means nothing - it can be a network going down, a wrong input to your app (from a search-engine for example), etc. So don't do anything on these exceptions (apart from returning an error code to the client and logging it).

By spec a servlet has only one instance - that instance is used with many threads invoking the `service(..)` method. This means you should not have any instance variables in your servlets for them to be thread-safe. The single-threaded model is deprecated now.

Comment: Actually, it is a closed app, only accessible through a GWT interface so any exception is bad sign. This is a non time critical hospital application and the users already have error messages. This is for an automated monitoring software which needs to know if something is wrong to do something or send someone over. Maybe my service should "ask" all the service servlets if all is ok? Dicey subject.